# How to implement google authenticator for 2 factor authentication with WSO2 identity server 5.7?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to use Google Authenticator for 2-factor authentication with WSO2 identity server 5.7.0. The Google Authenticator should provide a One-Time Password which is valid only for a very short duration. Using the email id, password and OTP (generated from Google Authenticator) a user should be allowed to sign in into an application.

I cannot find how to implement google authenticator in the link mentioned below [WSO2 Identity Server Authenticators and Connectors Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Authenticators+and+Connectors)

Can anyone provide some steps in the direction to implement Google Authenticator with WSO2?

Note: I am not referring to using Google as a federated authenticator.

Comment: Are you referring to the TOTP authentication? then you can use https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+TOTP+Authenticator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me for your use case you don't need google authenticator you need email otp[1]. You can configure your email otp to generate from google. You can enable it as a second factor in authentication. So the first user will login using user name and password then user will be asked for the otp that generated from google. That will be sent to the user email account.

If you want to use the google authenticator to get the otp not the email then you should use wso2 totp. [2]

[1]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Email+OTP
[2].https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+TOTP+Authenticator